# Storing and Iterating through user inputs in C

Tags: c, function, for-loop, input, user-input

The program below asks the user to input 10 integer numbers and stores the user inputs in a corresponding array of 10 ints. When an input is done it should iterate through the already existing user inputs and print them out. I want to iterate through the stored values in `storedinputs` by using a function like `strlen()`, however the stored values are not strings but are integers. How could i do such a thing.

```
int main(void) {
    int storedinputs[10] = {0};
    int input;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("\nPlayer input:");
        scanf("%d", &input);
        storedinputs[i] = input;

        for(int s = 0; s < strlen(storedinputs); s++) {
            printf("Inputs %d", storedinputs);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Expected Output:

```
Player input: 1
Inputs: 1
Player input: 3
Inputs: 1 3
Player input: 60
Inputs: 1 3 60
```

Comment: For each `i` you have exactly `i+1` stored inputs.

Comment: You can't apply `strlen(storedinputs)`. You are passing the wrong type. The inner loop can be `for(int s = 0; s <= i; s++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fixed code including error checking.

1. Superfluous input needs to be skipped over (`while(fgetc(stdin) != '\n');`)
2. `scanf` has insufficient error checking capabilities. Use combination of `fgets` and `strtol`.
3. In the internal loop you need to terminate when outer loop counter is reached
4. You should not count invalid input (Therefore, I replaced outer for loop by a while loop)
5. You should not store invalid inputs in your array
6. You need to index your stored inputs when printing them out

--

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

// In contrast to #define this provides a nice means for grouping constants
// and it can be changed into a typedef, later on
// Furthermore, it's a compiler aware constant
enum {INPUT_COUNT = 10, MAX_INPUT_LENGTH = 20};

int main(void) {
    int input_count = 0;                    // The count of valid inputs
    char input[MAX_INPUT_LENGTH + 1] = {0}; // The string buf for one input
    int converted_input;                    // Result of integer conversion
    int storedinputs[INPUT_COUNT] = {0};    // Array with valid results
    char *endptr;                           // Needed for strtol error checking

    while(input_count < 10) {               // Loop over 10 valid inputs
        printf("\nPlayer input (Enter single integer value):");
        fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
        printf("Got input: %s\n", input);   // input contains '\n', already

        // If input was longer than MAX_INPUT_LENGTH, get rid of remains
        if (input[strlen(input) - 1] != '\n') {
            while(fgetc(stdin) != '\n');
        }

        // Reset errno, so strtol returns a fresh value
        errno = 0;
        converted_input = strtol(input, &endptr, 10);

        // The errno is set if input is out of range
        if (errno) {
            perror("Conversion error");
            continue;
        }

        // Here we have invalid characters present in the input
        if ( (endptr == input) || (*endptr != '\n') ) {
            printf("Please enter single integer!\n");
            continue;
        }

        // Everything fine, so we can store result
        storedinputs[input_count] = converted_input;

        // Now we output all valid inputs, up to now
        printf("Inputs: ");

        for(int s = 0; s <= input_count; s++) {
            printf("%d ", storedinputs[s]);
        }

        printf("\n");

        ++input_count;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Player input (Enter single integer value):12
Got input: 12

Inputs: 12 

Player input (Enter single integer value):13 
Got input: 13

Inputs: 12 13 

Player input (Enter single integer value):14
Got input: 14

Inputs: 12 13 14 

Player input (Enter single integer value):1324567543245678654324567
Got input: 13245675432456786543
Conversion error: Numerical result out of range

Player input (Enter single integer value):asdc
Got input: asdc

Please enter single integer!

Player input (Enter single integer value):
Got input: 

Please enter single integer!

Player input (Enter single integer value):12 12 12
Got input: 12 12 12

Please enter single integer!

Player input (Enter single integer value):1
Got input: 1

Inputs: 12 13 14 1 

Player input (Enter single integer value):2
Got input: 2

Inputs: 12 13 14 1 2 

Player input (Enter single integer value):3
Got input: 3

Inputs: 12 13 14 1 2 3 

Player input (Enter single integer value):4
Got input: 4

Inputs: 12 13 14 1 2 3 4 

Player input (Enter single integer value):5
Got input: 5

Inputs: 12 13 14 1 2 3 4 5 

Player input (Enter single integer value):67
Got input: 67

Inputs: 12 13 14 1 2 3 4 5 67 

Player input (Enter single integer value):7
Got input: 7

Inputs: 12 13 14 1 2 3 4 5 67 7
```

OK, 10 inputs have been made

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the function `strlen()` because `storedinputs` is an array of integers. If you want to print the stored values every time you insert a new one you should edit the for loop condition, as suggested by Weather Vane in the comments, as follows:

```
for(int s = 0; s <= i; s++)
```

The variable `i` indicates the number of the cell containing the last number added.

Comment: This is right, but unfortunately not the only problem with the original code. E.g., missing error checking and as well in the inner loop the array was not indexed.